# HTML is showing up in the pop-up when leaving a Collective

Tags: bug, status-completed, collectives

While unsubscribing from a Collective, I got a pop-up which contains HTML tags in the response. Here's a screenshot for your reference:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pinging us on this! We're on it, should be fixed fairly soon :). We'll update this post whenever the fix is out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We recently moved to encoding all messages by default and turning on html only for non-user generated strings that needed it. Some got missed in the migration and we've been playing cleaning up, so appreciate the report!

Should be all set now

[image: Example of encoded and properly rendered collective leave notice]

**Related MSE Post**: [Badly escaped HTML results in plain text instead of markup in toast notifications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377743/209031)